# Check whether a Java thread is yielding

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

I am writing a customized Java scheduler, which schedules threads based on priority policies (the priorities are set and modified during the scheduling).

However, with `Thread.yield()`, the scheduler may run into deadlocks. For example, `t1` is calling a `Thread.yield()` and gives up the CPU. But since `t1` is still in the `RUNNABLE` state, my scheduler will stay attempting to schedule `t1` and stalling others.

I am looking for some ways to know whether a thread is "yielding", so that the scheduler can let another one to run. Any ideas?

Comment: `yield` doesn't mean the thread should be suspended indefinitely -- just that it _may_ be suspended for a bit. Developers who use it correctly will assume that the thread will continue to be scheduled and make progress. When it's used (and as the javadocs mention, it's rarely appropriate to use it!), it's often a way of making sure that one thread doesn't hog a CPU, _not_ as a way of parking a thread until some condition is met. In other words, if your scheduler continues to schedule `t1` despite the call to `yield()`, then it's working correctly. And if it _doesn't_, it's seriously broken.

Comment: (With all that said... I didn't even think the JVM lets you define a custom scheduler, and a cursory search seems to confirm that. So I'm not really sure what you mean.)

Comment: not trying to be rude here, but do you think your schedueler will perform better than the Linux/Windows one? what you described is basically setting the priority and let the OS do the rest. Even the JVM ditched the idea of Java-land scheduling in favor of OS scheduling. the OS has better idea than you which thread should run in every process in the system, just think of the number of people that worked on thread scheduling on the linux kernel and the amount of optimizations they performed. I doubt you can beat that

Comment: @David Haim The goal is not to replace the original one, but control the interleaving of threads and try to expose specific types of concurrency bugs. See the PCT (Probabilistic Concurrency Testing) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.currentThread() != threadInQuestion